# kdb/Q Can't left join on multiple columns when one column is a date

Tags: join, left-join, kdb

I have two tables, where each have multiple columns. A description of each table is below:

table_a

| column | type | first row |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name | char | Amy |
| date | date | 2023.01.01 |
| dist | float | 32.2 |

...

table_b

| column | type | first row |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name | char | Amy |
| date | date | 2023.01.01 |

...

I'm trying to left join on both name and date, as there are instances of people appearing twice on different days.

I tried the following:

```
joined_tables: table_a lj `name`date xkey select name, date, ... from table_b;
```

However, I get the following message:

```
'date
  joined_tables: table_a lj `name`date xkey select name, date, ... from table_b;
                                                                                                       
                                                                        ^
```

I can't seem to get those two columns joined and I'm asking the community for help, if anyone has experienced something similar before and can help provide suggestions.

I think it might be because the date column is of type date, does it have to be changed to symbol? I tried to cast but it would give me an error.

Comment: By any chance is `table_b` missing the column `date`?

Comment: It does not, both tables have the date columns, and it looks like they're both the same date type

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Comment: Is this data in an HDB or loaded into memory in a q process? How is the date column created? Where is the data coming from? Maybe have a read through the chapter 14 of Q for Mortals, you might find the answer to your solution in there https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb%2B/

Answer (score 1):

You need to carry out a (select on table_a) e.g.

```
joined_tables: (select from table_a) lj `name`date xkey select name, date, ... from table_b;
```

Assume you are working on a partitioned database, thus you need to either select the entire table as shown above or add a where clause and specify the date e.g.

```
joined_tables: (select from table_a where date =x) lj `name`date xkey select name, date, ... from table_b where date =x;

For example, mounting hdb:

$ q hdb/

q)t
date       sym  open  high  low   close volume
------------------------------------------------
2006.10.03 AMD  24.5  24.51 23.79 24.13 19087300
2006.10.03 MSFT 27.37 27.48 27.21 27.37 39386200

q)q
date       sym  price
---------------------
2006.10.03 AMD  1234
2006.10.03 MSFT 4567

q)t lj 2!select date,sym,price from q
'date
  [0]  t lj 2!select date,sym,price from q
         ^
q))\

q)(select from t)lj 2!select date,sym,price from q
date       sym  open  high  low   close volume   price
------------------------------------------------------
2006.10.03 AMD  24.5  24.51 23.79 24.13 19087300 1234
2006.10.03 MSFT 27.37 27.48 27.21 27.37 39386200 4567
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on a small example? This works just fine.

```
q)a:([]name:`a`b`c;date:.z.d+1 2 3; dist:10 20 30)
q)b:([]name:`a`b;date:.z.d+1 2; city:"ab")
q)a lj `name`date xkey b
name date       dist city
-------------------------
a    2024.01.12 10   a
b    2024.01.13 20   b
c    2024.01.14 30
```

Comment: Yes, it seems like the example you gave above works fine, but for some reason on my two tables I get an error. Maybe there are multiple date types?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly your tables are but this definitely works

```
q)t1:([] name:`Alex`Steve`Chris;date:.z.d+til 3;dist:3?1.0)
q)t1
name  date       dist
--------------------------
Alex  2024.01.11 0.3927524
Steve 2024.01.12 0.5170911
Chris 2024.01.13 0.5159796
q)t2:([] name:`Alex`Steve; date:.z.d+til 2; v:2#4)
q)t2
name  date       v
------------------
Alex  2024.01.11 4
Steve 2024.01.12 4

Here are 3 different ways of joining the data

q)t1 lj 2!t2
name  date       dist      v
----------------------------
Alex  2024.01.11 0.3927524 4
Steve 2024.01.12 0.5170911 4
Chris 2024.01.13 0.5159796

q)t1 lj `name`date xkey t2
name  date       dist      v
----------------------------
Alex  2024.01.11 0.3927524 4
Steve 2024.01.12 0.5170911 4
Chris 2024.01.13 0.5159796

q)t1 lj `name`date xkey select name,date,v from t2
name  date       dist      v
----------------------------
Alex  2024.01.11 0.3927524 4
Steve 2024.01.12 0.5170911 4
Chris 2024.01.13 0.5159796
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the 2nd and 3rd ways earlier and they produced the same error (above in my post), but when trying the 1st way I get the same error, except now it's highlighting the 2nd table's date column as the error, so it's closer than before